# visual studio jquery intellisense setup with other scripts

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

jquery intellisense works fine with standard setup (asp.net mvc)

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js in same folder

if added new script to head like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jq intelisense stops working

so how to add new scripts like above and keep intelisense working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the vsdoc.js file in a

```
<%if(false){%>
<%}%>
```

construct, to hide it from the live site but still have VS2008 process it.  Do this after the CDN script inclusion.

Comment: hmm, I've added like you suggested this but still no intellisense
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<% if (false) { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js"></script>
<% } %>

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this code for controls that are dynamically load in the page. put this code in your ascx file:

```
<asp:Panel ID="teste" runat="server" Visible="true">  
   <% If (false) {%>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/BaseLibrary/jquery.js"></ script>        
   <%}%>  
</ Asp: Panel>
```

I hope this will help you and sorry for my English.